# big commerce stencil product images

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I can get the default product image from the 'product card model'.  Is there a way to get the second gallery image?  I need the image path for a hover over.

Or alternatively, anyway to pass an additional image url to the product card?

- This is specific to BigCommerce stencil platform and the product objects map accessed via handelbars.  https://goo.gl/7d1cVk

The common product card model has an 'image' attribute. I don't see an attribute to list images.  I'd like to get the second gallery image (for a hover image) - without an expression for that I'm wondering if there is another way to get a second product image.

- Cheers

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you can provide more details.

Comment: This is specific to BigCommerce Stencil platform.  - Added some detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieving all images for products within the context of a category, brand, or search page at page load time is not currently supported. In order to retrieve all images for a specific product you must be within the context of that product.

Currently the only way to retrieve all images for a product is by loading the product details page, or making an ajax request for a specific product from any context where the target product ID is available.

The ajax solution is currently the only way to pull images for a product into a category, brand, or search context. This solution be most simply implemented with the Stencil Utils package, where you can call `stencilUtils.api.product.getById(productId, callback)`, and do as you wish with the resulting data.

Take a look at our quick view implementation to get a better idea of how these ajax calls work, keeping in mind that our core theme uses a module system to import Stencil Utils.

https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil/blob/master/assets/js/theme/global/quick-view.js#L18

PS - If you are not a Stencil early access developer, you might not have access to that link. We're currently in the process of sorting out our open source requirements.

Comment: Thanks Nell - exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: So stencilUtils.api worked well to get the images.  And I can use `{{#each product.images}}` to show all images. Is there a loop index custom helper ?

Comment: @PGrapes You should be able to use `@index` to access the current index. So `{{#each product.images}} {{@index}} {{/each}}`.

Comment: @dstaley Right but what about a way to return second image in array - something like `{{counter @index}}` or `getImage[2]`

Comment: @PGrapes If you don't want to iterate over the images, you can access the specific index of an array like this `{{ this.1.url }}`.